# How can you adjust cubes or objects precisely to each other?

Tags: modeling, texturing, modifiers, objects, vertices

[image]

Hello,
Iam currently working on a house model, and found the problem that objects are impossible allign in a precise manner with mouse adjustments..
Is there a option to control the position of my upper cube more precisely to the one one below? The objects are always tildet somehow and theres always a crack which I outline in the circle..
Ive searched many tutorials but they just don't suggest the right thing to do in this specific case. If I press x y or z to straighten them they just become completely tilted..

I'd be thankful for answers

best
G

Answer (score 1):

Try it with these settings here (and of course turn snapping on):

[image]

then you can do this:

[image]

be aware...the movement is a bit difficult, but you will get it after a short while.

After it snapped to the right face, you can press G X X to align it to the local x axis by moving with cursor.
Same with G Y Y and align it to your local y axis.